# Encoding a RawRepresentable enum crashes on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, enums, codable

Says I have an enum with raw values like so:

```swift
enum Foo: String, Codable {
    case bar
}
```

For some reason, I need to encode it and decode the data later. The following is how I encode/decode it

```swift
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(Foo.bar)
let foo = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: data)
```

This works well on iOS 13, but I get an error on iOS 12.

```
The data couldn't be written because it isn't in the correct format.
```

Is there any suggestion to fix this on iOS 12?

Comment: May be this answer will work for you -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44582674/7512091

Comment: I just found there are already tickets about this, https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6163, https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7213

Comment: Unrelated - use do-catch block and print error in the catch block to know the actual reason behind the issue.