# How do I make an enum codable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, enums, encode

I have a nested an `enum` inside a `struct` that I want to conform to `Codable`. How do I make the enum `codable` and therefore make the `struct` codable?

Here is an example of what I have:

```
struct Person: Codable {
  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String 
  var favoriteColor: Color

  enum Color {
    case blue, red, green, yellow, pink, purple
  }
}
```

Then, I get two errors :

> Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
>
> Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

How can I fix this problem?

**Edit**

I have also tried conforming Color to Codable. Xcode adds these protocol stubs:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
  <#code#>
}
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
  <#code#>
}
```

What would I do with this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `Codable` to `Color`?

Comment: Do you mean conforming Color to the Codable protocol?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: `enum Color: String, Codable` (or whatever raw value you want to use). If you don't want to use a codable-friendly raw value then you will have to implement the decode/encode yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580719/how-do-i-make-an-enum-decodable-in-swift-4/44582674

Answer (score 8):

```
struct Person: Codable {
     var firstName: String
     var lastName: String
     var favoriteColor: Color
}

enum Color: String, Codable {
   case blue, red, green, yellow, pink, purple
}
```

Comment: What does this do with my Color enum? Does this modify it in any way?

Comment: It declares that the Color enum value is a String

Comment: Just a note: the enum need not be declared inside the struct declaration.

Comment: @nighttalker you are absolutely right, thanks for mentioning it.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Note there's nothing wrong with it being defined inside the struct either. Really depends on the context. If this enum is specific to Person it might as well be nested.