# What is the most appropriate way to initialise an enum from some JSON data in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, enums, swift5, codable

I want to initialise a `Shape` enum from some JSON data, but I feel like the way I am doing it may encounter errors, and I am wondering if there is a safer or more standard way to initialise an enum from some JSON.

A snippet of the JSON data I have looks like the following:

```
"foo": [
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "enemyShape": "triangle",
        },
```

I am able to access the data through a `Codable` struct [like this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/7/3/parsing-json-using-the-codable-protocol):

```
struct Enemy: Codable { //data about all the pegs
    
    let name: String
    private let enemyShape: String
    
    public var shape: Shape {
        return Shape(enemyShape)
    }
    
}
```

And my code to initialise the enum `Shape(enemyShape)` is the following:

```
enum Shape: CaseIterable {
    case triangle
    case square
    case pentagon
    
    
    init(_ str: String) {
        switch str {
            case "triangle":
                self = .triangle
            case "square":
                self = .square
            case "pentagon":
                self = .pentagon
            default:
                self = .triangle
                print("Shape initiated with invalid value \(str). Defaulted to triangle.")
        }
    }
}
```

I am worried that this is not safe or a proper way to do this - especially because of the code under `default:` that will never execute, but has to be used for the code to compile.

Is there a better way to get an enumerator from JSON? All I need is for some string, e.g `"triangle"` to initialise a `.triangle`, `"square"` a `.square`, etc.

**Edit:** Note that when I am not initialising this enum directly from the JSON data, which is why I think it is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580719/how-do-i-make-an-enum-decodable-in-swift-4/44582674) question. I also want to be able to initialise an enum from a 'similar' string at any point in the code, without necessarily using any of the JSON data at that point in time.

I am able to initialise this way at any time with [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1780632/jawadali)'s method, so I've accepted his answer.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580719/how-do-i-make-an-enum-decodable-in-swift-4/44582674) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make an enum Decodable in swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580719/how-do-i-make-an-enum-decodable-in-swift-4)

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for the link - that information will be useful in the future, but I don't think it directly answers my question.  I also want to be able to initialise an enum from a 'similar' string at any point in the code, without necessarily using any of the JSON data at that point in time. The answer from jawadAli allows me to initialise from a string at any point, whether I am using it or not, so I have accepted his answer.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson same as above - I can't @ two people at once, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enum directly like this

```
enum Shape:String, Codable, CaseIterable {
    case triangle = "triangle" 
    case square = "square" 
    case pentagon = "pentagon"
}
```

Comment: This does what I want, only I have to write `Shape(rawValue: "square")`. This isn't a big issue, but is it possible to get rid of the `rawValue` in the initialiser?