# Using SwiftUI Picker with RawRepresentable enum that contains associated values crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, userdefaults, appstorage

I'm working on an app that enables users to choose default and custom fonts.

```swift
// MARK: - CustomFont

enum CustomFont: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case baskerville = "Baskerville"
    case chalkboardSE = "ChalkboardSE-Regular"
    
    var displayTitle: String {
        switch self {
        case .baskerville:
            return "Baskerville"
        case .chalkboardSE:
            return "Chalkboard SE"
        }
    }
    
    var id: String {
        rawValue
    }
}

// MARK: - AppFont

enum AppFont: Hashable, Codable {
    case `default`
    case custom(font: CustomFont)
}

// MARK: - RawRepresentable

extension AppFont: RawRepresentable {
    init?(rawValue: String) {
        let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8)!
        self = try! JSONDecoder().decode(AppFont.self, from: data)
    }
    
    var rawValue: String {
        let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(self) // EXC_BAD_ACCESS CRASH HERE
        return String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
    }
}
```

I need to persist those fonts as [Codable RawRepresentable enums in AppStorage](https://nilcoalescing.com/blog/SaveCustomCodableTypesInAppStorageOrSceneStorage/).

```swift
// MARK: - ContentView

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("selectedFont") private var selectedFont: AppFont = .custom(font: .baskerville)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $selectedFont) {
                Text("Default")
                    .tag(AppFont.default)
                
                ForEach(CustomFont.allCases) { customFont in
                    Text(customFont.displayTitle)
                        .tag(AppFont.custom(font: customFont))
                }
                
            } label: {
                Text("Select font")
            }
            
            if case let .custom(font) = selectedFont {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .font(.custom(font.rawValue, size: 17))
            } else {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I know for a fact that it's the `Picker` that crashes the app.
The app hangs for several seconds, and the JSON encoder crashes with the generic EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I've already tried [embedding the enum into a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44582674/7337547). But it yielded the same result.

Here's [a concise sample project](https://github.com/genebogdanovich/SwiftUIPickerIssue).

I don't know if it's on me or if I should submit a bug report. Does anybody have any idea of what I might be doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the Picker that crashes the app at all, instead it is the encoding of `AppFont` that enters an infinite loop because in the property `rawValue` the function call `.encode(self)` calls `self.rawValue` because you have declared that `self` conforms to `RawRepresentable` so the encoder wants to encode the raw value of the enum case.

Note what it says in the article

> Remember, that AppStorage only supports RawRepresentable where the RawValue's associatedtype is of type Int or String. So the rawValue property has to return an Int or a String.

But the AppFont enum does not have a RawValue of type String or Int, in fact the enum can not be made to properly conform to RawRepresentable since it has a case with an associated value.

Maybe this should be seen as a compiler bug and that the compiler should produce an error here.

To work around this you can skip the Codable support and use with `switch` when converting to/from a string

```
extension AppFont: RawRepresentable {
    private static let defaultRawValue = "default"

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        switch rawValue {
        case Self.defaultRawValue:
            self = .default
        default:
            guard let font = CustomFont(rawValue: rawValue) else { return nil }
            self = .custom(font: font)
        }
    }

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .default:
            return Self.defaultRawValue
        case .custom(let font):
            return font.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

---

I didn't include SWiftUI or UserDefaults when examining this, instead this was my test code

```
var rawStrings = [AppFont.default.rawValue]
for font in CustomFont.allCases {
    let string = AppFont.custom(font: font).rawValue
    rawStrings.append(string)
}

for string in rawStrings {
    if let font = AppFont(rawValue: string) {
        print(font)
    }
}
```